# What do you call a character that acts as a prop in a film?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a character that acts as a prop in a film? In my understanding, prop is used for objects, but is there a word for human characters acting as props?

Comment: I would call them a prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person used as a prop in the movie world is an **extra**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/extra) has

> **extra**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1.2** A person engaged temporarily to fill out a crowd scene in a film or play.
>
> *the film used an army of extras*

---

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(acting)) definition is

> A background actor or **extra** is a performer in a film, television show, stage, musical, opera or ballet production, who appears in a nonspeaking or nonsinging (silent) capacity, usually in the background